# Dishwasher and both sinks stink like rotten eggs

Tags: plumbing

I've cleaning everything and nothing works.  I know its unsanitary so I've been washing my dishes by hand.  I think it must be related to a drain line some how. But I don't know what exactly I'm looking at under there.  I do know I don't have an aerator.

Comment: neither do we know what you're looking at.  - post a photo.

Comment: Do you have a Natural Gas Stove in the kitchen. There is an additive in Natural Gas that makes it smell like Rotten eggs so you know when there is a leak. Try smelling around your stove to see if the smell is stronger if it is you need to pull the stove out and turn the valve off the supplies gas to the stove. If you have a gas leak it is a dangerous situation. I do not know if you have a gas leak I’m simply suggesting investigate further